# permutation on path

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying a special case of graph , permutation graph in which $G(V,E$)  is a path graph from source $s$ to a destination $d$ , adding new Ep Edges which are a permutation of ($v_i,v_j)$ $\in V$ with condition that the source and the destination remain in the same position, in other words we permute only nodes between $s$ and $d$.

My question, how to find the minimum length of the shortest path $s$~$d$  in the worst case.

Comment: please edit your typos, it's really annoying to have about 8+ misspelt words in a question of about 40 words

Comment: Isn't the worst case the identity permutation, where there are no extra edges and the path passes through every vertex?

Comment: the permutation are added to the path graph, my question is about how does the shortest path lenght vary according to the permutation.